# Equivalent of Androids DiffUtil for Swift / iOS or other effective implementation

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, diff

In my app I have to load some data from a web service. Then I have to sort the data by properties of models of a collection property of the model and then update my collectio view with the new data.

Unfortunately I have no clue how I can know which cell moved to which new position. On Android, I used DiffUtil in the past but I'm not aware of a Swift equivalent to animate the changes in my collection view.

Heres the data model I use. For the this example, I omit all the other fields and use protocols to make it clearer (at least I hope this makes it clearer):

```
protocol Alert {
  var date: Date
  var statusType: StatusType
}

protocol Status {
  var statusType: StatusType
  var level: Level
}

protocol Device {
  var states: [Status] //Contains never more than 1 Status of each StatusType so its basically a set
  var alertsByStatusType: [StatusType: [Alert]]
}

enum StatusType {
  case someStatus, someOtherStatus
}

enum Level {
  case low, medium, high
}
```

The web service returns me a device which contains a collection of Status and a collection of Alert.

```
//Web service model kind of sucks
protocl WebServiceDevice {
  var states: [Status]
  var alerts: [Alert]
}
```

In the device constructor, I do some manually sorting and mapping to build the `alertsByStatusType` dictionary. I also sort the `Status` collection by the `Status.level` so that first, all "high" level states come, then the "medium" level and finally the "low" level states.

Inside the same level, I then have to sort by the `Alerts.date` so when two `Status` have the same `Level`, the one with the more recent `Alert` comes first.

I know, this data model I get from the web service is terrible to begin with and I begged for a proper model where the alerts are inside their corresponding states and the states are properly sorted but hey, thats life.

Now when I display all states in a tableview, let's say a `Status` with `level == low` gets and alert, then the level will change and after updating my data from the web service and sorting everything, it will be further to the beginning in the `Device.states` collection. **How can I know from which indexPath I have to move the cell to which new indexPath?**

I hope you understand what I mean and what the problem is. Basically I have to find out which `Status` has a different `Level` and from where to where it has moved in the data source of my table view so I can animate the changes instead just call `reload()` on the table view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why but the answer I selected as correct for this question has vanished so I thought I'd answer it myself. I was pointed to a library which can do exactly that and by the time of writing, I found more libraries.

They probably all have their ups and downs and the one I use now is the Dwifft Library (https://github.com/jflinter/Dwifft)

Other interesting diff libraries can be found here: https://awesome-repos.ecp.plus/ios.html under the *Data Structures / Algorithms* section

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's IGListKit does really good job when it comes to deal with arrays in a list view(i.e. UICollectionView) thanks to [ListDiff](https://instagram.github.io/IGListKit/Functions.html#/c:@F@IGListDiff) function.